# Cannot retrieve cookies in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I am trying to have a login function in **codeigniter** model, but cannot retrieve cookies there.

It returns bool false.

I have tried searching for the problem,one of the problem was cookies were not being set,
but my cookies are being set in the browser, under domain localhost. And I have tried using cookies on localhost earlier in a different project, without codeigniter, in which I was able to retrieve cookies on localhost.

Here `$_COOKIE['username']` would throw error invalid index 'username', `$this->input->cookie('username')` would return `bool(false)`. But I can see 'username' cookie in my browser.

Cookies set and retrieved are on different files.

```
public function checkLogin(){

    $this->load->helper('cookie');

    $row['user']    = $this->input->cookie('username', TRUE);
    $row['handle'] = $this->input->cookie('email', TRUE);
    $row['id']      = $this->input->cookie('pid', TRUE);
    $row['type']    = $this->input->cookie('type', TRUE);
    $row['slug']    = $this->input->cookie('slug', TRUE);
    $row['cuid']    = $this->input->cookie('cuid', TRUE);

    return  $this->input->cookie('username', false);
    }
}
```

I set the cookies in a different file,

```
setcookie("username",$user, time()+60*60*60*24*30);
setcookie("email",$handle, time()+60*60*60*24*30);
setcookie("pid",$row['id'], time()+60*60*24*30*60);
setcookie("type",$type, time()+60*60*24*30*60);
setcookie("slug",$row['slug'], time()+60*60*24*30*60);
setcookie("city",$row['city'], time()+60*60*24*60*30);
setcookie("cuid", $code, time()+60*60*24*60*30);
```

Please ask for more information needed. I have used construct function(two underscores) in my controller, not in model. The form where cookies are being set is not in controller or model but in root folder. And I have tried setting cookies using `$this->input->set_cookie();` too.

Comment: if you are trying to use the cookie helper you need to try use it a bit differently. Check out the manual http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html

Comment: You say that you can see the username cookie in the browser, does it have a value set?

Comment: yes,it has the correct value set @Jeemusu

Comment: @micb I can't see what am i missing.

Comment: what is the domain they are set to, and what is your sites domain?

Comment: @Jeemusu do you have any piece of code that works fine on your system, i can try on mine involving cookies.

Comment: @optim i think you should set the cookie using the options for path and domain also. see this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php. Give the path as "/" and domain as localhost. Something like `setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600, "/", "localhost");`

Comment: @optim `setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600, "/", "localhost");` use this statement and please clear you browser cookies before checking. Also please make sure the time on your PC & Apache(server) is set correctly.

Comment: @UmairKhan the path that the browser shows for this cookies "/forms/accounts"

Comment: @optim ok, i think it's getting set from somewhere else then. The reason iam thinking is that if it's being set by the statement i  mentioned before it should set it as "/". Is it possible that you run the root script only in which you are setting the cookie mentioning the path "/" and then check what path is being set in browser cookie? Please clear all of your browser cookies before running this script. Atleast one thing is now obvious that it's path problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localhost may set path according to files that set the cookie.

Declare path explicitly.

```
setcookie("username",$user, time()+60*60*60*24*30, "/");
```

Cookies with path "/" can be retrieved anywhere, otherwise not.